# Entity Framework's code-first migration fails with FormatException, probably bug

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

## The problem

I've ran into a problem recently, I have pretty standard set of model classes that describe my business logic, I'm using fluent Api to describe the database properties of my model classes. But after I'm doing `Add-Migration InitialMigration` the Package Manager Console fails with the following output:

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
Scaffolding migration 'InitialMigration'.
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildColumnModel(XElement property, String entitySetName, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass125.<BuildCreateTableOperation>b__123(XElement p)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildCreateTableOperation(String entitySetName, String tableName, String schema, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<FindAddedTables>b__31(XElement es)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

At first it was not clear what string was not in appropriate format, it took me several days working out different approaches but I've ended up with nothing. As a last point of defence I debugged Visual Studio and Entity Framework code that does the required scaffolding and it turned out that the problem was lying within `NVARCHAR(MAX)` mapping of `string` fields. Somehow Entity Framework was treating term `MAX` as an integer constant causing the `FormatException` during the parsing process.

## The guess

I think that the problem lies within project configuration or mixture of Fluent Api with Attribute api (The model was copied from other project that used attributes to describe the database properties of the model, migrations were working and everything was ok, then I removed attributes and used fluent api to describe the model and it stopped working)

I think that probably I missed some configurational point or misused the fluent api.

## The question

Is there a way to make Entity Framework treat correctly a default `NVARCHAR(MAX)` declaration and make it stop parsing `MAX` as an integer...

[Here I've uploaded the project itself in case you would want to see the problem by your own eyes...](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51743054/EF-Problems/flightmanagementsystem.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `MaxLength` attribute (with [parameterless constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696366.aspx) to annotate a string with a maximum length. In Sql Server this will translate to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

You can also use the fluent [IsMaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.lengthpropertyconfiguration.ismaxlength%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method, as in:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Property(x => x.Description).IsMaxLength();
    ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, even if I set all string fields to integer values, the problem persists with some strange `History` table which contains `nvarchar(max)` field to which I have no access, this is probably an internal Entity Framework table that is used under covers...

Comment: Can't you re-create the database? Or do you have to roll back the latest migration and migrate again?

Comment: But this attribute/mapping is supposed to solve the format exception. Do you mean you still get this exception when you use this attribute/mapping?

Comment: Yes, I do get this exception, I'm unable to create migration neither I can update my database, there's a link in the bottom of the question, where I've uploaded the whole project, you may open it and run "Add-Migration InitialMigration" in a package manager console

Answer (score 0):

Don't use IsMaxLength() and HasColumnType("nvarchar") at the same time. Remove the latter and it should work.